# Somar ocorrencias em um Memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Tenho os seguintes itens em um memo:

```
ns
ns
basica+textura+Al
ns
ns
ns
ns
basica+textura+Al
basica+textura+Al
basica+textura+Al
basica+textura+Al
ns
ns
ns
```

Gostaria que ele somasse quantas vezes o `ns` aparece.
Tentei usando o `memo1.Lines.IndexOf('ns');`, mas ele só traz uma ocorrencia.

Acredito que se encaixa um loop até o final do memo, porem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percorra todo o memo comparando as linhas a ns

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  n, i  : Integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  for n := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
      if ( memo1.Lines[n] = 'ns' ) then
          Inc( i );
  end;
  ShowMessage('ns foi encontrado ' +  IntToStr( i ) + ' vezes ');
end;
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pela ajuda